# when querying the same table ,spark sql return null values but hive and impaly get nomal data?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hiveql, parquet, impala

I have a table in hive

[image]

Query the same table in two ways:

1. hive  or impala: I get the expetcted results like this

```
0: jdbc:hive2://cdh-master3:10000/> SELECT * FROM kafka_table.risk_order_user_level_info rouli WHERE rouli.month = '2019_01' AND rouli.day = '08' androuli.order_id >0 limit 5;
INFO  : OK
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--+
| rouli.order_id  | rouli.order_type  | rouli.uid  | rouli.po_id  | rouli.status  | rouli.user_level  | rouli.pre_user_level  | rouli.credit  | rouli.down_payment  | rouli.open_order_id  | rouli.createtime  | rouli.month  | rouli.day  |
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--+
| 39180235        | 2                 | 10526665   | -999         | 100           | 10                | 106                   | 27000         | 0              | -999                 | 1546887803138     | 2019_01      | 08         |
| 39180235        | 2                 | 10526665   | -999         | 100           | 10                | 106                   | 27000         | 0              | -999                 | 1546887805302     | 2019_01      | 08         |
| 39180235        | 2                 | 10526665   | -999         | 100           | 10                | 106                   | 27000         | 0              | -999                 | 1546887807457     | 2019_01      | 08         |
| 39180235        | 2                 | 10526665   | -999         | 100           | 10                | 106                   | 27000         | 0              | -999                 | 1546887809610     | 2019_01      | 08         |
| 39804907        | 2                 | 15022908   | -999         | 100           | -999              | -999                  | 0             | 85000              | -999                 | 1546887807461     | 2019_01      | 08         |
+-----------------+-------------------+------------+--------------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--+
```

2. but usr spark  whate python or scala ,I got this,several colums are null

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT * FROM kafka_table.risk_order_user_level_info WHERE month = '2019_01' AND day = '08'  limit 5").show()
+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+----------+--------------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---+
|order_id|order_type|     uid|po_id|status|user_level|pre_user_level| credit|down_payment|open_order_id|   createTime|  month|day|
+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+----------+--------------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---+
|    null|      null|14057428| null|    90|      null|          null|2705000|        null|         null|1546920940672|2019_01| 08|
|    null|      null| 5833953| null|    90|      null|          null|2197000|        null|         null|1546920941872|2019_01| 08|
|    null|      null|10408291| null|   100|      null|          null|1386000|        null|         null|1546920941979|2019_01| 08|
|    null|      null|  621761| null|   100|      null|          null| 100000|        null|         null|1546920942282|2019_01| 08|
|    null|      null|10408291| null|   100|      null|          null|1386000|        null|         null|1546920942480|2019_01| 08|
+--------+----------+--------+-----+------+----------+--------------+-------+------------+-------------+-------------+-------+---+
```

#### How can I make sparksql return expected results ???

ps:
I execute the flowing sql in spark and hive find different results;

```
SELECT * FROM kafka_table.risk_order_user_level_info rouli
WHERE rouli.month = '2019_01' AND rouli.day = '08'
and order_id IN (
 39906526,
 39870975,
 39832606,
 39889240,
 39836630
)
```

[two results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ClQ6.png)
[image: two results]

this is where  this question posted this page hit me;

I also check the records' number of the table  in two ways above and the counts are same

Comment: Can you try and select particular row and then see if it has the data. Like select where order_id=39180235. Because what I'm seeing both of your outputs contains different **uid** .

Comment: 3KQ for reply ,update the question already

Answer (score 0):

Include `rouli.order_id >0` condition in you spark sql query as well. You will see non null records in your spark sql output .

Note: Limit will will return records randomly . The results shown in the above two scenarios belong to different order_ids .

Answer (score 0):

Solved  on my own.
the data in this tabel is writen by sparksql, but the name of field  in scala(spark) is diffent with hive (create table sql).

eg:orderID (scala) but order_id (sql)